# What causes the "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" and how to remove it?

Tags: crossfilter

I'm creating a crossfilter dimension using data from ajax. what is the right way of creating the dimension variable?

```
    var url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/twitter-data"; 

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
                makeGraphs(data);
        }

    });

    function makeGraphs(records){
        var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%H:%M");

        var data = records.map(obj => {

            var res = dateFormat.parse(obj._source.published)
            return res;
        });

        console.log(data[0]);

        //Crossfilter
        var ndx = crossfilter(data);
        var all = ndx.groupAll


        //Dimensions
        var hashtagDim = ndx.dimension( function (d) {return d.hashtags; }, true);
```

'

The error on the console looks like:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> > at quicksort (crossfilter.js:172)
> >
> > > at sort (crossfilter.js:169)

and it continues like this.

The last line on the code snippet produces the error. I have seen solutions that say it is a recursive function call but i am not sure what I need to change on my code to avoid this error.

Comment: The [javascript] tag will only bring you pain, friend. Unless your question is specifically about the language, no one will know what you're talking about and they will try to close your questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you certain there is a ´hashtag´ property on your data elements?

Commonly, when I have run into the same error using crossfilter, it has been because I have been attempting to register a dimension using a non-existing property (i.e. the value function returns `undefined`). Using a wrong case for a property will also result in an `undefined` return value, as properties are case sensitive.

Generally, a dimension (or group) value function may never return `NaN`, `undefined`, or `null`: [Natural ordering of dimension and group values](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#natural-ordering-of-dimension-and-group-values).

A possible underlying cause is if you are initiating your crossfilter before your AJAX request is complete. But this is just guesswork, as I do not know enough about your code.

Comment: Hi, @matthias.rocks I've added more code to make it clearer. when using the debugger, I'm unable to verify if there is indeed something inside, but when creating the "data" variable I can reference hashtags.  I'm not entirely sure how to put all the dictionary values into the data variable.

Comment: @mattias.rocks has nailed it. You need to make sure `hashtags` is populated (and an array) for every row in the data set. You could put `console.assert(d.hashtags && Array.isArray(d.hashtags))` inside your dimension key function in order to find the bad entries.

Comment: @Mahlatse Could you include an example of your data? E.g. just a single (representative) entry from your `data` array.

Comment: I have successfully seen where the problem lied. Thanks mattias.rocks and @Gordon for the debug tips. mattias.rocks my data is in a dictionary. instead of just accessing it at d.hashtags i was supposed to do d._source.hashtags hence d.hashtags had nothing and made that error. I had tried it at first but it was giving a different error but now it works fine.

Comment: @Mahlatse Makes sense - glad to hear you got it working!